# 3 separate ArrayList

Tags: java, class, arraylist

ACME wants to layoff some employees. Using three ArrayLists, form three lists of employees. The first list will contain all the programmers, the second all the non-programming people making over one hundred thousand dollars, and the last all other people. Using separate loops print out the contents of each ArrayList. (The following are what I did, but not work... looking for help)

```
import java.util*;
class Employee
{
private String name;
private String address;
private String position;
private double salary;
private String getName()
{return name;}
public String getAddress()
{return address;}
public double getPosition()
{return position;}
public double getSalary()
{return salary;}
public void setName(String aName)
{name=aName;}
public void setAddress(String aAddress)
{address=aAddress;}
public void set(double aPosition)
{postion=aPosition;}
public void setSalary(double aSalary)
 {salary=aSalary;}
public employee(String aName, String aAddress, double aPosition; double aSalary)
{

name=aName;
address=aAddress;
position=aPosition;
Salary=aSalary; }
public String toString() 
{return name+address+position+salary;}
}

class employee
{public static void main(String[] args)
{Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Employee[] Newemp=new Car[500];
for(int i=0, i<Newemp.length;i++)
{System.out.print(“Enter the name”);
String name=in.nextLine();
System.out.print(“Enter the address”);
String address=in.nextLine();
System.out.print(“Enter the position”);
double position=in.nextDouble();
System.out.print(“Enter the salary”);
double salary=in.nextInt() ;
in.nextLine();
Newemp[i]=new Employee(name, address, position, salary);
}


ArrayList<Employee>programmers=new ArrayList<Employee>();
ArrayList<Employee>nonprogrammers=new ArrayList<Employee>();
ArrayList<Employee>others=new ArrayList<Employee>();
for(int i=0; i<Newemp.salary; i++)
{if(Newemp[i]. getposition().equals(“programmer”))
programmers.add(Newemp[i]);
else if(Employee[i].getsalary()>100000
nonprogrammers.add(Newemp[i]);
else
others.add(Newemp[i]); 
 }
for(int i=0; i<programmer.();i++)
{
Employee<=programmer.get(i);
System.out.println(i);
}}}
```

Comment: "but not work". Can you elaborate?

Comment: `Employee[] Newemp=new Car[500]`?  What's a `Car`?

Comment: (a) Please use your IDE's "format" menu option to indent your code properly. Then edit your question and paste the properly-formatted code. (b) You need to explain exactly what didn't work. Did it have errors? If so, what errors? Did it display output you didn't expect? If so, what was the output you expected and what was the real output? (c) Why `new Car` in an employee question?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<Newemp.salary; i++)`?  `salary` is the length of `Newemp`?  Are you sure?

Comment: position is string getter returning double,postion not declared, ; inside constructor, i<Newemp.salary really?, programmer not declared. And what do you expect to work here?

Comment: Well, *that* code for sure won't compile: 1) First class is called `Employee`, but constructor is `employee`. 2) Constructor has a semicolon between `aPosition` and `aSalary`. 3) Field is named `salary`, but constructor assigns to `Salary`. 4) Field `position` is a `String`, but getter, setter, and constructor is `double`. 5) Second class is called `employee`. On Windows, that would cause file name conflict, because file names are not case-sensitive. 6) Second class is not `public`, so `main()` method cannot be invoked. *7) I'm out of comment space to continue...*

Comment: Dang, I missed the very first line: Missing `.` before `*` on the `import` statement. --- On another topic, while not an error, I hope the user of the program is *very* patient, having to enter 500(!) employees, 4 values at a time. 2000 enter keys later, and oops, typo in salary of employee #314. Start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this will help

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Newemp.length; i++) {
            if (Newemp[i].getPosition().equals("programmer")){
                programmers.add(Newemp[i]);
               System.out.println("programmers"+programmers);
            }
            else if (Newemp[i].getSalary()> 100000)
                    {
                        nonprogrammers.add(Newemp[i]);
                          System.out.println("salary 100000 thousand"+nonprogrammers);
                    }  else{
                        others.add(Newemp[i]);
                        System.out.println("others"+others);
                    }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < programmers.size(); i++) {
            EmployeeData aa= programmers.get(i);
            System.out.println("All aaray"+aa);
        }
```

Comment: These really helped. And by the way, Can I change" Length" into anyother word? What's the proper word should I use for 'for (int i = 0; i < Newemp.length; i++) '   @Chandan Sarma

Comment: to find out the arraysize use generally use arrayname.lenght method. you cannot changes it as its a java method.

Answer (score 0):

in your main()

```
for(int i=0; i < Newemp.salary; i++)
...
else if(Employee[i].getsalary()>100000
```

should be:

```
for(int i=0; Newemp[i] != null; i++)
...
else if([i].getsalary()>100000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I hope you understand the concept of object, the methods & variables available with the array can not be mixed with others and vice-versa. `length` is a variable inside the array object which returns you the size. I would suggest instead of declaring a huge array and then iterating through it. Directly add your objects into an ArrayList as given below. I hope it helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String position;
    private double salary;`

    public Employee(String aName, String aAddress, String aPosition,
            double aSalary) {
        name = aName;
        address = aAddress;
        position = aPosition;
        salary = aSalary;
    }

    private String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        name = aName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String aAddress) {
        address = aAddress;
    }

    public void set(String aPosition) {
        position = aPosition;
    }

    public void setSalary(double aSalary) {
        salary = aSalary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + address + position + salary;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSize = 500;
        ArrayList<Employee> programmers = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        ArrayList<Employee> nonprogrammers = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        ArrayList<Employee> others = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the name");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the address");
            String address = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the position");
            String position = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the salary");
            double salary = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            Employee newEmployee = new Employee(name, address, position, salary);
            if (position.equals("programmer"))
                programmers.add(newEmployee);
            else if (salary > 100000)
                nonprogrammers.add(newEmployee);
            else
                others.add(newEmployee);
        }

    }
}
```